# Please explain what's wrong with cannibalism

Tags: sunless-sea

In several places in Sunless Sea, there are locked storylets that require the quality Unaccountably Peckish. I'm pretty sure you pick that up from turning cannibal. (As the tagline goes, LOSE YOUR MIND. EAT YOUR CREW.) And right now, I'm staring at an option involving the Sigil-Ridden Navigator that's much, much cheaper if I'm Unaccountably Peckish, and I've seen that quality unlock a couple of minor storylets in Adam's Way and Gaider's Mourn, too.

So it looks like there's something to gain from violating one of humanity's more sacred taboos. Is there a downside to sampling Long Pig? Aside from the [somewhat-inconvenient tableware](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cannibal%20fork)?

Comment: Half of this question's upvotes will be because of its title.

Comment: Although a clearer title (which would still have the same effect) might be "Does cannibalism have any downsides?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Currently no downsides. I extracted all the interactions from the gamefiles. There's one thing where you get a slightly different outcome for cannibal vs not, but there's no benefit to staying untainted.

(and quite a few upsides to enjoying that dark delicious meat).

Answer (score -2):

I can't speak for the specific effects of Unaccountably Peckish in Sunless Sea, but in Fallen London it's one of the Menace qualities and is linked to a quest that pretty much brings nothing but woe.  The game even says things like "This is a bad idea.  Don't do this." in a number of places.

To further not-answer your question, sometimes you may need a bit of menace to progress in certain quests.  I've only had Unaccountably Peckish once in Sunless Sea, but I think it was then used in... a certain scavenger-hunt.

Comment: I've played Fallen London, and more-or-less finished the current content; I suppose I should have mentioned that. But even there, Unaccountably Peckish doesn't cause any actual *problems* unless you deliberately chase *other* bad choices; there isn't even a Place of Menace for it. It just *sounds* really bad, and the game's text makes it seem unspeakable, plus it'll cost you a few actions and resources to reduce it. The Foreign Office just makes it sound worse - but again, no mechanical penalties.

Comment: @PaulMarshall true. Though there are some cards/storylets whose available actions change with UP, they aren't any more required to act upon than anything else.

Comment: @PaulMarshall Also, could I trouble you to have a look at my question here about the whisper-locked box?

Comment: I can't answer that question, I'm afraid. I haven't created a new captain since the box was introduced, though I did give the box to a zee-captain.